# how to insert header and footer to existing pdf document using itextsharp (without overriding the existing content of the page)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf-generation, itext

In my project I am using MVC4,C# and itextsharp to generate pdf from html. I need to insert header with a logo and template name, and footer with paging (page number/Total number of pages). I am done the the footer, I have used this code to add footer to the pdf file:

```
public static byte[] AddPageNumbers(byte[] pdf)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
            // we create a reader for a certain document
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
            // we retrieve the total number of pages
            int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
            // we retrieve the size of the first page
            Rectangle psize = reader.GetPageSize(1);

            // step 1: creation of a document-object
            Document document = new Document(psize, 50, 50, 50, 50);
            // step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
            // step 3: we open the document

            document.Open();
            // step 4: we add content
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;



            int p = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("There are " + n + " pages in the document.");
            for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                document.NewPage();
                p++;
                PdfImportedPage importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, page);

                cb.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, 0);

                BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                cb.BeginText();
                cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, +p + "/" + n, 44, 7, 0);
                cb.EndText();


            }
            // step 5: we close the document

            document.Close();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

if you need any explanation about this code please let me know.

I tried to use the same method for header but my site logo is overriding the existing content of the pdf page. Then i tried to use this code but no luck :(

```
       public _events(string TemplateName,string ImgUrl)
        {
            this.TempName = TemplateName;
            this.ImageUrl = ImgUrl;
        }
        private string TempName = string.Empty;
        private string ImageUrl = string.Empty;

        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
        {


            //Paragraph footer = new Paragraph("THANK YOU ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL));




            Paragraph header = new Paragraph("Template Name:" + TempName + "                             " +DateTime.UtcNow, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL));

            //adding image (logo)

            string imageURL = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images.jpg");
            iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageURL);
            //Resize image depend upon your need
            jpg.ScaleToFit(140f, 120f);
            //Give space before image
            jpg.SpacingBefore = 10f;
            //Give some space after the image
            jpg.SpacingAfter = 1f;
            jpg.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;


            header.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;

            PdfPTable headerTbl = new PdfPTable(1);

            headerTbl.TotalWidth = 400;

            headerTbl.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

            PdfPCell cell11 = new PdfPCell(header);
            PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(jpg);
            cell2.Border = 0;
            cell11.Border = 0;

            cell11.PaddingLeft = 10;
            cell2.PaddingLeft = 10;
            headerTbl.AddCell(cell11);
            headerTbl.AddCell(cell2);

            headerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, doc.LeftMargin, doc.PageSize.Height - 10, writer.DirectContent);

  }
    }
```

here is my Action method to which is returning the pdf file as response. and i have used this class in it. apologies may be I should post this in beginning of my question.

```
[HttpGet]
[HandleException]
public ActionResult GenerateLeadProposalPDF()
{
    TempData.Keep();
    long LeadId = Convert.ToInt64(TempData["Leadid"]);
    long EstimateId = Convert.ToInt64(TempData["Estimateid"]);
    long ProposalTemplateId = Convert.ToInt64(TempData["ProposalTemplateId"]);
    Guid SubscriberId = SessionManagement.LoggedInUser.SubscriberId;
    var data = this._LeadEstimateAPIController.GetLeadProposalDetails(LeadId, EstimateId, ProposalTemplateId, SubscriberId);
    System.Text.StringBuilder strBody = new System.Text.StringBuilder("");
    string SubscriberProjectBody = this.ControllerContext.RenderRazorViewToString(ViewData, TempData, "~/Areas/Subscriber/Views/Shared/_GenerateProposalTemplate.cshtml", data);
    string Header = this.ControllerContext.RenderRazorViewToString(ViewData, TempData, "~/Areas/Subscriber/Views/Shared/_HeaderGenerateProposals.cshtml", data);
    string styleCss = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/ProposalDoc_CSS.txt"));
    strBody.Append(@"<html><head><title></title>   </head>");
    strBody.Append(@"<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>");
   // strBody.Append(Header);
    strBody.Append(SubscriberProjectBody);
    strBody.Append(@"</body></html>");
    String htmlText = strBody.ToString();
    Document document3 = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 36, 36);
    _events e = new _events(data.objProposalLeadDetailsModel.ProposalFullName,"test");
    string filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/");
    filePath = filePath + "pdf-.pdf";
    var stream=new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
  var objPdfWriter=  PdfWriter.GetInstance(document3, stream);
    document3.Open();
    objPdfWriter.PageEvent = e;
    iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document3);
    hw.Parse(new StringReader(htmlText));
    document3.Close();
    var result = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    var abd = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    var streamArray = ReadFully(abd);

    var streamFile = AddPageNumbers(streamArray);




    // Response.End();
    string contentType = "application/pdf";
    return File(streamFile, contentType, "LeadProposal.pdf");
}
```

I have searched a lot over google, my pdf looks like this [image: the logo is overriding the existing content see]

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated, Please help me, thanks in advance :)

Comment: For pre-existing PDFs you might prefer a process like the one in the [TwoPasses.cs](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter06/TwoPasses.cs) example.

Comment: it will also override the existing content @mkl

Comment: Use `GetUnderContent` instead of `GetOverContent`. Or use transparency.

Comment: what if I need to add 100 or more line in the beginning (header) or at the end (footer) of my pdf file. can we create space for these extra content? I don't need my new content over or under on existing content, I need to place my new content with old content with same layout.

Comment: *I need to add 100 or more line in the beginning (header) or at the end (footer) of my pdf file* - do you mean "above the current top of the page" / "below the current bottom of the page"? As soon as you know how much space you need, you can simply expand the media box (and other boxes if present) to get space for the extra content. Or do you mean something like "between current header and the content" / "..."? That could prove difficult.

Answer (score 0):

after some changes in the _events class I got what I want, but may be its not the right way to do it, but for now its working for me :)

```
public class _events : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        public _events(string TemplateName,string ImgUrl)
        {
            this.TempName = TemplateName;
            this.ImageUrl = ImgUrl;
        }
        private string TempName = string.Empty;
        private string ImageUrl = string.Empty;

        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
        {
            Paragraph PTempName = new Paragraph("Template Name:" + TempName, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL));
            Paragraph PDate = new Paragraph(DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString(), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL));

            //adding image (logo)

            string imageURL = "http://108.168.203.227/PoologicApp/Content/Bootstrap/images/logo.png";//HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images.jpg");
            iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageURL);
            //Resize image depend upon your need
            jpg.ScaleToFit(70f, 120f);
            //Give space before image
            //jpg.SpacingBefore = 10f;
            //Give some space after the image
            jpg.SpacingAfter = 1f;
            jpg.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;


            PTempName.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
            PDate.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;

            PdfPTable headerTbl = new PdfPTable(3);

            headerTbl.TotalWidth = 600;

            headerTbl.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;

            PdfPCell cell11 = new PdfPCell(PTempName);
            PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(PDate);
            PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(jpg);
            cell2.Border = 0;
           cell11.Border = 0;
           cell3.Border = 0;

            cell11.PaddingLeft = 10;
            cell3.PaddingLeft = 10;
            cell2.PaddingLeft = 10;
            headerTbl.AddCell(cell11);
            headerTbl.AddCell(cell3);
            headerTbl.AddCell(cell2);

            headerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, doc.LeftMargin, doc.PageSize.Height - 4, writer.DirectContent);


        }
    }
```

now my pdf looks like this : [image]